# Issue about XML summary comments in VBNET

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Intellisense is not showing my parameter names in blue color like I saw in other xml comments from 3rd party projects where Intellisense prints all the information, this is what I see:

[image]

What modifications I need to do in my comments to let intellisense to print the parameter comments in blue as the "returns"?

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Function to pause a thread.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="Process_Name">The name of the process, ex: cmd.exe</param>
    ''' <param name="Thread_Number">The thread to pause, ex: 0</param>
    ''' <param name="Recursive"> <value name="True">Pause the thread in all processes recursively</value></param>
    ''' <returns>True if the process is found; otherwise, False.</returns>
    Public Shared Function Pause_Thread(ByRef Process_Name As String, _
                              Optional ByVal Thread_Number As Int32 = 0, _
                              Optional ByVal Recursive As Boolean = False) As Boolean
```

Comment: What *version* of VS?  It's important.

Comment: @RBarryYoung VS 2012 Ultimate, thanks

Comment: The customary convention in .NET code is to *camelCase* parameter names. They should always start with a lowercase letter, like `processName`. I'm sure this isn't why Intellisense is broken, but it does look a little strange...

Comment: @Cody Gray I've tried to change the Word-case of the param names to camelCase but anything in Intellisense has changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]Try to install the Productivity Power Tools addin

- VS 2010 - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/.
- VS 2012 - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd.

From what I see you are looking for the Colorized Parameter Help.

> **Colorized Parameter Help**
>   This extension improves consistency with the editor by applying syntax highlighting to the contents of the Parameter Help window for C# &VB. Please note: Syntax highlighting colors can be customized using the display items prefixed with “Signature Help” in the “Fonts and Colors” menu.

Try Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Signature Help Tooltip Background.

Comment: Thanks but that's not a valid solution for me for two reasons: 1. The Addon is not compatible with my version of VS (VS 2012), 2. I saw parameters in blue colors in other project classes without using external addons on my IDE

Comment: I've installed that extension but is not showing any extra info of the summary code above (I don't know if I need to make modifications), also nothing to do with fonts and colors options.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML comments are correctly configured.  You will start to see them when you put the first "(" in your code.  You can see all of the comments via View; Object Browser.  It looks like this:

```
Public Shared Function Pause_Thread(ByRef Process_Name As String, Optional Thread_Number As Integer = 0, Optional Recursive As Boolean = False) As Boolean

Member of VB_NET_TEST.WebForm1
Summary: Function to pause a thread.

Parameters:
Process_Name: The name of the process, ex: cmd.exe
Thread_Number: The thread to pause, ex: 0
Recursive: Pause the thread in all processes recursively

Return Values:
True if the process is found, otherwise, False.

Remarks:
```